# Share the browser session (cookies, local storage) between computers

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I need to transfer my Chrome session between 2 computers.

To export and import the cookies via Selenium you have to visit each website individually before you can set its cookies, and I want to avoid that. I also want to copy over the local storage.

When I copy the user data directory on my PC then it works and the cookies are there, however, when I copy this user data directory to another PC and launch it, then the local storage is still there, but the cookies are gone.

Comment: Wouldn't chrome's native sync handle this?

Comment: can't use the chrome's native sync, because I want to do this programmatically (if possible) and on a larger scale than 2 machines

Comment: @RiTu If you can program then try and make an application yourself. I mean I would definetly use it if something like it exsisted. I also suggested the idea to a friend of mine who's also a programmer. Hopefully in the future we will have an extension or program that will share cookies.

Answer (score 7):

> No, you cannot share cookies across web browsers. At present, there
>   are no services that synchronizes cookies just like how bookmarks are
>   synchronized.
>
> It does not make sense for you to share a cookie across
>   browsers or even machines, because cookies are supposed to be used to
>   identify unique sessions. Most web applications are also intelligent
>   enough to handle simultaneous access of their service from multiple
>   devices. For example, you can use Facebook or Gmail on your smartphone
>   and laptop without causing any synchronizing issues.

[source](https://superuser.com/questions/271710/synchronize-cookies-between-browsers/527668#527668)

There are some google chrome extensions that might intrest you. For example take a look at this extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-free-multi-log/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig

Create an account. Log in into multiple devices and quickly share you browser session. It's working pretty good so far. The sync time is almost instant and it is very nice and easy to use. Yes it does do the sessions per website but adding a new website session is not hard at all and doesn't take alot of time. They also have a paid version which is only $1 per month and it gives you some extra things.

On thing I am missing with this extension is that it doesn't share cookies / passwords so I don't have to login again on every site. I searched some more but I couldn't find anything that shares cookies/passwords automatically. I hope sessionbox will implement that feature sometime.

Comment: you can try copying the ./firefox directory in Ubuntu