# Cookies Transfer From Google Chrome To Firefox

Tags: cookies

I want to transfer few cookies from google chrome to Firefox.

Could you please help me, how can I do this process?

Comment: I would start by looking for a cross-browser extension that allows you to export the cookies from Chrome and import them into Firefox.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/271710/synchronize-cookies-between-browsers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Synchronize Cookies Between Browsers](https://superuser.com/questions/271710/synchronize-cookies-between-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

If Chrome and Firefox are installed on the same computer:

- Open Firefox
- Go to menu *Bookmarks > Manage Bookmarks*, or use
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- Click on "Import and Backup"
- Click "Import Data from Another Browser..."
- Select "Chrome"
- Click Next
- Select your profile
- Click Next
- Select Bookmarks (and anything else you would like to transfer)
- Click Next to finish.